# Blogdown website with wowchemy theme is not rendering interactive plots and table

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown, wowchemy

I am using [wowchemy theme](https://github.com/wowchemy/starter-hugo-academic) for a blog. Initially, the visualization from ggplot2, plotly, and HTML table from DT::datatable was not rendering.

The static visualization is rendered using the following code.

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.path = "static")
```

But, This didn't render the interactive visualization and HTML table from DT and rmarkdown::paged_table().

Comment: I'm not having any issues with these and that theme. However, what you're working with has many moving parts. I will say that the Blogdown manual specifically states not to alter the `knitr` defaults for `fig.path` or `cache.path`. Are you executing the code to create the plots to render them? Or are you saving them and adding them as images? Do they work when you render the RMD that contains just that content?

Comment: Just for the record, this was cross-posted at https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/715.